# php - regex to format operators in a expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to get all operators (arithmetic, comparison, logical...) in a string...

```
((value+10)*10)>=300   ||   (array[key]-20==0&&"foo==bar"!=="")
```

...and add a single whitespace before and after them (if doesn't already exists)...

```
((value + 10) * 10) >= 300 || (array[key] - 20 == 0 && "foo==bar" !== "")
```

...ignoring what is between quotes or single quotes.

Aditional rules:

- add space only before pre-in/decrement operators
- add space only after post-in/decrement operators

Sounds easy but I can't get how I could do it using regex in PHP. Thanks if someone can help!

I'm trying to do something like `$str = preg_replace('(?<=[\w\]\)\s\"\'])\!=(?=[\w\]\)\s\"\'])', ' != ', $str);` for every operator, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: I would love to repair your regex if you made one.

Comment: @MarinoBoscoloNeto - I'd still stick that code in your post just so it demonstrates that you've made the effort.

Comment: Should `(-20+3)` be `(- 20 + 3)` or `(-20 + 3)`?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes (-20 + 3) is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this pattern works with PCRE Engines, which I believe php is

```
"[^"\r\n]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*([\-\/+*=|<>!&]+)\s*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/339)

Answer (score 0):

I would use three regexes:

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOT
(-20+3)
((value+10)*10)>=300   ||   (array[key]-20==0&&"foo==bar"!=="")
EOT;

$str = preg_replace('/("[^"]*"|\([^+=&<>|*\/\\%\w\d-]*|-?\d+|[\w[\]]+|\))/', ' $1 ', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\() +| +(?=\))/', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $str);

print_r($str);
```

[Check it live here.](http://ideone.com/GsmzR1)